# Restricting access to methods of a class

Tags: c++, oop, private, encapsulation

I have a class A which has public methods and used by 100 other classes implemented in different applications. Now I want to make those public methods as private so that no new classes access them, but I want the existing client classes to still access them. 
But I don't want to even touch those client classes , because the owners seldom allow even any ripple in their classes.

I checked

[Can I access private members from outside the class without using friends?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424104/can-i-access-private-members-from-outside-the-class-without-using-friends)

[C++: Is there a way to limit access to certain methods to certain classes without exposing other private members?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2902717/c-is-there-a-way-to-limit-access-to-certain-methods-to-certain-classes-withou)

[friend class with limited access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609472/friend-class-with-limited-access)

But all ( not all really ) demand a change in the client's code. The client code should not change.

One straight forward way is to make all those N classes friends , But I am somewhat not comfortable doing that. Is there any pattern or an acceptable technique ( not a hack please ) to achieve this access restriction? 
Thank you and I apologize if this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classes in C++ are made `friend`s in order to indicate an special intentional strong coupling between classes. This use of `friend` infact enhances Encapsulation rather than break it as maybe the popular feeling.
How?
Without friendship the only non-hack way to expose the functionality to other class would be to provide `public`, `get` and `set` member functions,this in fact breaks encapsulation because all classes(even those who don't need to) now have access to these methods and hence the members increasing the risk of potentially breaking down the class data.

Back to your situation, If you have a 100 classes which need access to this particular class, then you already had the right design in-place by having those methods as `public`. Now trying to make those methods `private` to future classes is a trying to hack your existing design, Your design does not support it.

Making the existing classes as `friend`s does not ideally fit in the above mentioned criteria and hence is not a good choice for the scenario.
However, given the situation there is no other way in which you can implement this. Making the existing classes as `friend` and granting them the special access seems the only way. This is still bad because the 100 classes which only had access to the few methods will now have access to your entire class.

Comment: He can declare only some methods as "friend" and not the whole class.

Comment: @Idov: Oh Yes, If only specific methods inside those 100 class need access then that is possible OP surely can do that.In that case the last point I said doesnt apply.However I am not sure what is the exact situation,I quoted the worst case scenario.

Comment: @Idov: Thank you very much. If I understand you correctly , the caller methods ( of different classes ) should be declared as friends. I tried it out in a test program and it worked. Thank you very much. Can a few methods in a class ( int this case it is A ) be declared as friends and yet private , so that the friend class methods have access only to them apart from the public interfaces?

Comment: @user917279: Yes,A method can be declared as `private` in its own class and it can be declared a `friend` of other class.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can extract an interface of the `A` class (let it be `IA`) and make `A` to implement `IA`. You should not define those public methods in `IA` at all.

Then, old code will continue using `A` and will have access to `A` public methods, while new code will use restricted interface, that code would receive through some fabric .

Of cause, this can be unimplementable, if you need to (copy-)construct class, or smth like this, but I can't say it now without knowing the usage of class.

Also, you get a little overhead due to `virtual` functions